# psql: error: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, psql

I have ssh into an ubuntu server where I have postgresql installed, however I keep getting the error when trying to connect to a database 192.xxx.xxx.xx

psql: error: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.xxx.xxx.xx", user "xxxx", database "xxxx", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.xxx.xxx.xx", user "xxxx", database "xxxx", SSL off

I've edited postgresql.conf file listen_address = '*'

and edited pg_hba.conf as follows

local          all         postgres            trust

host           all         all     0.0.0.0/0     md5

host           all         all     ::0/0         md5

However I still keep getting the same error

Comment: can you share the psql command with option that you are using to connect to this postgres instance.

Comment: did you restart the postgres server for this changes takes effect ?

Comment: psql -h 192.XXX.XXX.XX -d xxx -U xxxx

Comment: Yes I did restart postgres after

Comment: @lssac follow this thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host you have some suggestion that you can try apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the PostgreSQL server:

```
$ service postgresql restart
```

For further info, you can check out [here](https://www.techaeblogs.live/2022/11/could-not-connect-to-postgresql-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host.html)